# Spring boot Web Socket Connection loosing connection on production

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, websocket

I am using Angular, Spring Boot, and WebSocket in my project. I'm testing on my local machine socket connection is working fine but when I deployed my build on the production server it is not working properly. sometimes connection was established and sometimes not. I'm new to this technology.

I already configured the message broker and WebSocket application endpoints here is my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://www.xxxxxx.com/").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chatparticipant", "/messages", "/unAssignedParticipant");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024000);
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/socket").setAllowedOrigins(Pl4ChatConfig.ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
    }
}
```

we're getting error messages:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxx.com/ws/709/2pjkwf4q/websocket' failed: